# Shutdown/logoff script in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: shutdown, restart, scripts, logout, automatic

Which would be the best way to run a script upon GUI logoff, shutdown, hibernate, sleep modes? In 12.04 I think I did this in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, but on 13.10, the folder structure changed and when I create this script, The display manager wont even start upon boot.

I am looking to implement a simple automatic truecrypt unmount command

```
truecrypt -d
```

but of course this would go for any script.

Edit: 
The file doesn't exist, and if I create it and just put the lines

```
session-cleanup-script = /path/to/executable/script.sh
```

, After reboot I can't log in anymore until I delete the file anymore. This also happens if The File starts with

```
[SeatDefaults] 
session-cleanup-script = ...
```

How come this is not working at all, and/or why the file doesnt exist in the first place? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, should look like:

```
[SeatDefaults]
session-cleanup-script=/path/to/executable/script.sh
```

Try also in terminal to see what is happening when you assign a value to a variable like this: `a = b` and when you assign a value to a variable like this: `a=b`. First variant will give you all the time a `command not found` error. So, please, *don't put spaces around the `=` in assignments!*

Comment: Ok, thanks, that worked. Apart from the space in the assignment, the main problem in the end was that I got over-eager and added a session-setup-script at the same time, which contained a non-accepted command (truecrypt scripted mount), and then I couldnt even log in with the lightdm.conf in place. Am I right to assume that reboot and shutdown also log out the user?

Comment: A normal (not forced) reboot/shutdown, yes, imply a successful log out of all currently logged users.